# How to check is user is login using htacess

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-redirect

Before hitting the link of my website say example.com/bla then it has to check weather the user is login or not if he login then go to that above link if not then he should visit the login page using htaccess.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^$
    RedirectMatch 302 ^/(.*) http://myexample.com/login.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

How would I check using htacess user is login or not.

Comment: You've got the right idea, just the wrong approach.  Probably best to use PHP sessions for this, as well as a user table that contains usernames and passwords.

Comment: Setup up a session with PHP in order to recorgnize users. https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Assuming you just want a quick feature, without checking for security, you can set a cookie from login.php on afterLogin event, and remove this cookie on afterLogout event. You can read the cookie into .htaccess :
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*is_logged=true [NC]
But it is not secured, you have to check the validity of the identity into your php script each call

Comment: i wanted to achieve this-
if someone hits the url like -
http://myexample.com/sales or http://myexample.com/test ,it should redirected to index.php which is present in the root of my domain for user authentication if session exist then it should redirected in the previous url which was hitted

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done using .htaccess.  You will have to write this functionality into a php script and store the credentials using a server session.